# Use bash history file from old machine when setting up new machine?

Tags: bash, command-history

I love my bash history.  Sometimes I've issued really long commands and I really depend on my bash history to get them back quickly.  I've increased my history size with:

```
HISTSIZE=100000
HISTFILESIZE=200000
```

in my .bashrc

I also have aliases:

```
alias h='history | tail'
alias hg='history | grep'
```

which allow me to do `h` and `hg some_text` which is *really* handy

My question is:  Can I move this history file to a new machine?  For instance my machine recently crashed and I had to rebuild it.  Would I have any issues dropping a different .history file in, possibly replacing the one already there.  Do I need to make sure to replace it or can I actually append two history files together without issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can copy the old history file to a new install. You can also merge it with old / new.

- If you do not have `HISTTIMEFORMAT` set the history file only holds commands.
- If it is set there is a timestamp preceded by a hash for each command:

  ```
  #1122334455
  command1
  #1122334459
  command2
  ```

Note however that if you issue e.g:

```
$ echo 'foo
> bar
> baz' >> some_file
```

It is going to be saved as:

```
#1122334459
echo 'foo
bar
baz' >> some_file
```

But `history` is going to show:

```
4 CMD_TIME echo 'foo
5 CUR_TIME bar
6 CUR_TIME baz' >> some_file
```

Commands like:

```
$ foo | \
bar | \
baz
```

are preserved as one if you set `shopt -s cmdhist`.

---

I use various but often something like:

```
HISTSIZE=500000
HISTFILESIZE=500000
# Ignore dupes and space commands
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
# Save and show timestamps
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
# Save and reload the history after each command finishes
# This one I have a function to turn on/off. Effect is that commands are
# accessible in all terminals after execution.
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

- More [on `shopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html). (Use `$ shopt` to show current settings.)
- More [on `history`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Builtins).

---

I also back up history files regularly and have some scripts and aliases to search history – even many years back in time. Sometimes I recall I did something similar to what I'm currently doing 1.5 years ago and can quickly look up in history.

As for timestamps I use two variants. `history` shows with timestamps and another show without by temporarily setting `HISTTIMEFORMAT` to "".

---

If timestamp is missing current time (approximately) is used.
If timestamps are present history is sorted by times.

Thus:

`.bash_history` (Timestamps simplified)

```
#timestamp 000012
some command
#timestamp 000002
some other command

$ history
1 13 aug 2013 10:44 some other command
2 13 aug 2013 12:13 some command
```

It is however reasonable to believe that a sorted history file is more effective (bash doesn't have to do any shuffling).

---

As for lookup <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> is often useful. For other things look at e.g. [Commands For Manipulating The History](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-History), [Event Designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators), [Some Miscellaneous Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Miscellaneous-Commands) etc.

Answer (score 3):

*I think* that you can move the file without issue, or append also.

for append:

```
cd ~
mv .bash_history .bash_history_new
cp /mnt/oldfs/home/olduser/.bash_history ~/
cat .bash_history_new >> .bash_history
```

if you got any issue you can undo this:

```
mv .bash_history_new .bash_history
```

Answer (score 3):

My `.bash_history` is usually just a symlink to `/dev/null` (ie, my history is never saved on disk).  Consequently, when I start a shell, there is no history to access.  *However*, a history does accumulate, meaning that bash does this in memory, not in the history file.  In fact `man bash` says (under **HISTORY**):

> On startup, the history is initialized from the file named by the
>   variable HISTFILE (default ~/.bash_history). [...] When the history file
>   is read, lines beginning with the
>          history comment character followed immediately by a digit are interpreted as timestamps for the preceding history line.  These 
>   timestamps  are  optionally  dis‐
>          played  depending  on  the  value  of the HISTTIMEFORMAT variable.  When an interactive shell exits, the last $HISTSIZE lines
>   are copied from the history list to
>          $HISTFILE.

I left the bit about the timestamps in because this helps to explain the format of the history file if you look at it (it is a plain text list).  The main point here is that the history file is only used when the shell first starts, and then again when it exits (to append recent history).

Since the format is simply a list of commands interspersed with timestamps, and bash will work fine even if the file contains nothing (such as with the /dev/null link), then I can't imagine there being any negative consequences of importing one.  You could probably even manually append stuff into it, omitting the timestamps -- at least, you could try it.  If the shell screws up, just exit and restore the old history.

You should also be able to use multiple histories for multiple purposes if you want, by swapping files or exporting `$HISTFILE` before you start the shell.  If you set them read-only (or perhaps reset `$HISTFILE` subsequently? This depends on whether the shell checks that variable at the end, or uses the initial value), then they won't be appended to when the shell exits either.